# Issue with orbeon forms

Tags: orbeon

I have 2 issues in orbeon forms. first the attachments are not working Im getting the below error while attaching files 
"A Submission error parse error occured"

but there are no errors on the console of browser please find the screen shot

clicking on calendar gives the below javascript errors only on IE

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'value' of undefined or null reference

SCRIPT5009: 'console' is undefined

are there any fixes for this attached screen shots and JS code snippet

{this.lastError=D;if(A){throw D;}}}return B;},unsubscribeAll:function(){var A=this.subscribers.length,B;for(B=A-1;B>-1;B--){this._delete(B);}this.subscribers=[];return A;},_delete:function(A){var B=this.subscribers[A];if(B){delete B.fn;delete B.obj;}this.subscribers.splice(A,1);},toString:function(){return"CustomEvent: "+"'"+this.type+"', "+"context: "+this.scope;}};YAHOO.util.Subscriber=function(A,B,C){this.fn=A;this.obj=YAHOO.lang.isUndefined(B)?null:B;this.overrideContext=C;};YAHOO.util.Subscriber.prototype.getScope=function(A){if(this.overrideContext){if(this.overrideContext===true){return this.obj;}else{return this.overrideContext;}}return A;};YAHOO.util.Subscriber.prototype.contains=function(A,B){if(B){return(this.fn==A&&this.obj==B);}else{return(this.fn==A);}};YAHOO.util.Subscriber.prototype.toString=function(){return"Subscriber { obj: "+this.obj+", overrideContext: "+(this.overrideContext||"no")+" }";};if(!YAHOO.util.Event){YAHOO.util.Event=function(){var G=false,H=[],J=[],A=0,E=[],B=0,C={63232:38,63233:40,63234:37,63235:39,63276:33,63277:34,25:9},D=YAHOO.env.ua.ie,F="focusin",I="focusout";return{POLL_RETRYS:500,POLL_INTERVAL:40,EL:0,TYPE:1,FN:2,WFN:3,UNLOAD_OBJ:3,ADJ_SCOPE:4,OBJ:5,OVERRIDE:6,CAPTURE:7,lastError:null,isSafari:YAHOO.env.ua.webkit,webkit:YAHOO.env.ua.webkit,isIE:D,_interval:null,_dri:null,_specialTypes:{focusin:(D?"focusin":"focus"),focusout:(D?"focusout":"blur")},DOMReady:false,throwErrors:false,startInterval:function(){if(!this._interval){this._interval=YAHOO.lang.later(this.POLL_INTERVAL,this,this._tryPreloadAttach,null,true);}},onAvailable:function(Q,M,O,P,N){var K=(YAHOO.lang.isString(Q))?[Q]:Q;for(var L=0;Lenter image description here

Comment: What version of IE?

Comment: Its IE11 running on enterprise mode. The attachment issue exists on both Chrome and IE

Comment: Which exact version of Orbeon Forms are you using?

Comment: We are using 4.5 version this does not support the above function.  The above functions are working fine on Orbeon 3.9 version. But unfortunately it does not support HTTPS in 3.9 version it says host name in certificate does not match

Comment: If you could share your mail contact I can share the war file and screen shots which has the issue

Comment: I see it's a fairly old version from 2014. Please contact Orbeon if you have commercial support.

Comment: We tried this with the latest versions also 2018 version same error occurred can you suggest anything for the same

Comment: Hi ebruchez, I wil summarize the issue :  We have been using Orbeon 3.9 till date from a very long time. Now, our application is upgraded to be https enabled. We upgraded the orbeon version to 2016 CE 3. We observed that SSL n HTTPS works fine, but attachment upload functionality fails with an error in IE and Chrome while using xf:upload tag. Can you please guide us which version of orbeon supports https -ssl and also supports xf-upload functionality. We will procure the license if needed as well bcoz it is a blocker issue. If you are not sure about the answer please provide the right contact

Comment: Any version of Orbeon Forms is intended to support HTTPS and `xf:upload`. For example [does this](https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/bookshelf/new) work for you if you try to attach an image?

Comment: Hi the attachment does'nt work for any type of file text,image,word etc

Comment: I meant on the link I provided above? This one: https://demo.orbeon.com/demo/fr/orbeon/bookshelf/new

Comment: Currently we are using 3.9 Version of orbeon which is supporting all our needs text,radio,dropdown and also attachments. As 3.9 version of Orbeon.war does not have built in properties for HTTPS support when we migrated the application from HTTP to HTTPS the Orbeon forms failed. Is there any option for us to include HTTPS properties in external file properties-local.xml that can be used in orbeon 3.9. In case we upgrade our version we are not sure of the impact of changes. Can we have a short call if possible

Comment: Maybe this doesn't have to do with HTTPS but with IE11 and Chrome 60. See [this discussion](http://discuss.orbeon.com/Chrome-60-breaks-Orbeon-3-9-td4662710.html) for details. But for more, you will need commercial support.